# Page Border for cover page in LaTeX

Tags: border, covers

I am trying to make a page border for cover page only (the first page) as shown in the figure.

[image: Page Border]

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want this specific design, or something like that?

Comment: Hi @RajaAyaz... Are you willing on using tikz package? I think it is the easier way and gives you really much abilities...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a tikz solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,inner sep=0,outer sep=0]
     \draw[blue!70!black,line width=4pt] ([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) coordinate (A)--([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north west) coordinate(B)--([xshift=1.5cm,yshift=2cm]current page.south west) coordinate (C)--([xshift=-1.5cm,yshift=2cm]current page.south east) coordinate(D)--cycle;

     \draw ([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]A)-- ([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=0.5cm]B)--
     ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=0.5cm]B) --([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]B)--([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]C)--([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=0.5cm]C)--([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=0.5cm]C)-- ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]D)--([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]D)--([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=0.5cm]D)--([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=0.5cm]A)--([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]A)--([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=-0.5cm]A);


     \draw ([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]A)-- ([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=-0.3cm]B)--
     ([yshift=0.3cm,xshift=-0.3cm]B) --([yshift=0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]B)--([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]C)--([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=-0.3cm]C)--([yshift=0.3cm,xshift=-0.3cm]C)-- ([yshift=0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]D)--([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]D)--([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=-0.3cm]D)--([yshift=0.3cm,xshift=-0.3cm]A)--([yshift=0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]A)--([yshift=-0.3cm,xshift=0.3cm]A);

   \end{tikzpicture}
\begin{center}
  {\Huge Title}\vspace{\fill}

  {\Large Author name}\vspace{\fill}

  \today
  \vspace{\fill}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome @RajaAyaz... we could automate it a little bit to have easier adjustable distances... But I think you get the point

Comment: Thanks, I tailored your solution to my needs a little bit and it works perfectly :)